# Can not connect to bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am new to bluemix. While connecting to bluemix by cmd prompt I get the following error. But I can create app succesfully directly through bluemix UI.

[image: error screenshot of command prompt]

Please convey if any specific settings are to be done.

Comment: Please, instead of taking a screenshot of the error, copy and paste the text into the question. That way, people searching for the same problem as you will find your problem, and its answers.

Answer (score 1):

1. uninstall Cloud Foundry command line...
2. delete your $HOME/.cf/*
3. run cf installer -- install it to default C: drive

download the latest version here: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases

Comment: It did not work. I tried uninstalling and installing it twice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the server don't allow you to connect. I remember that I had problems connecting to the USA API. I didn't face the same problem, however, try to connect to the UK API. Change the region in Bluemix UI and use the following command:

```
cf api https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net
```

Comment: Hi.. I tried connecting to all the three regions. All are connecting fine through UI but neither are getting connected through cmd promt.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on the [Bluemix Status Page](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status) recently we experienced some issues during login (both via cf and UI). However the issues should now be resolved, so I suggest you to verify that you are using the correct api URL before you log in. The API URLs are the following:

- US Region: https://api.ng.bluemix.net
- UK Region: https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net
- AU Region: https://api.au-syd.bluemix.net

Comment: Hi.. I tried connecting to all the three regions. All are connecting fine through UI but neither are getting connected through cmd promt.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking this kind of error is related to a permission issue. It would be worth to check either the Windows firewall or the user permissions.